# How could I send a mail via PhP Mailer?

Tags: javascript, php, phpmailer

I downloaded the composer and PHP mailer into my project using the xampp local server. I took an example of PHP mailer configuration from the packagist. I got a PHP index.php error --> Message could not be sent—Mailer Error: Message body empty.

```
$mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'This is a test email';
    $mail->Body    = `
    The user has left contacts <br>
    Name: $name <br>
    Phone: $phone <br>
    Email: $email
    `;
```

I have the error in the dev tools console, too -->

[image]

My jquery script looks like this -->

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "index.php",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
    }).done(function () {
      $(this).find("input").val("");
      $("#consultation, #order").fadeOut();
      $(".overlay, #thanks").fadeIn("slow");

      $("form").trigger("reset");
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Any suggestions, mates?

Comment: For `$mail->Body` you seem to be enclosing the string in backticks: `\`` rather than single quotes: `'`. Backticks are not valid for string delimiters, and have a wholly different meaning in PHP. Given the context, you likely want double quotes: `"`.

Comment: Can't I use backticks such as javascript?

Comment: @Sammitch I rewrote the body, and the error disappeared. I have left another problem with jquery; the input doesn't send a mail.        POST http://speedrunner.local/index.php 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:4

Comment: This question does not have a great title.

Answer (score 1):

You are using backticks instead of quotes around your message body. In PHP, backticks are an [execution operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php), so it will try to run your message body as a shell command, which will fail because it's not a valid command (and also represents a very large security hole in your app since you're including user-supplied data into it without escaping), and then try to assign the result of running it to the `Body` property. Not surprisingly, this will not do what you want. Since you want variable interpolation, double-quote it instead instead:

```
$mail->Body = "The user has left contacts <br>
Name: $name <br>
Phone: $phone <br>
Email: $email";
```

You might find that for long strings a [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) works better.